# Query for several same-level ancestors

Tags: google-app-engine

I have the following entities:

```
class Book():
  team = db.StringProperty()

class Entry():
  role = db.StringProperty()
```

I create two `Book`s:

```
book1 = Book(team='Plants').put()
book2 = Book(team='Zombies').put()
```

I create three `Entry`s:

```
entry1 = Entry(parent=book1, role='Peashooter').put()
entry2 = Entry(parent=book2, role='Gargantuar').put()
entry3 = Entry(parent=book2, role='Flag Zombie').put()
```

I can make a query for the `'Plants'` `Book`:

```
query = Entry.all().ancestor(book1).fetch(100)
```

I'd like to make a query for several books. I can only think of `list` concatenation:

```
list1 = Entry.all().ancestor(book1).fetch(100)
list2 = Entry.all().ancestor(book2).fetch(100)
query = list1 + list2
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this other than `list` concatenation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to combine queries for several different ancestors (that don't share a common ancestor), the only way to do it is with separate queries, as you demonstrate. This is no different than if you want to query for several distinct values in a field.